# Transactions are not mining for accounts created by Nethereum.Accounts.Account method but works for accounts created by web3.Personal.NewAccount

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nethereum

Transactions are not mining & in pending state for long time, for transactions with accounts created using Nethereum.Accounts.Account(privateKey).
But mining works for accounts created using web3.Personal.NewAccount.SendRequestAsync("password").

I am using below method to initiate transaction. 
web3.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(new TransactionInput(data.ToHexUTF8(), addressTo, senderAddress, gas, value))

I am running ethereum on my local environment with 1 node.